# Issue running Android Emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know what I am doing wrong. I originally had `vxt` enabled on this computer and was able to run emulator from Android studio. `HAXM` is installed and I thought I had re-enabled everything correctly but I must be missing it. I have read through the threads here and too this is not a new computer, it is a new hard drive. UEFI bios, I cannot run an emulator from Android studio. Presently I am updating Android Studio which is the last thing I wanted to do, I cannot however see another choice at the present time. Does anyone have any idea of what I am missing? It was working with the old hard drive. Windows 7-64 bit. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: You updated HAXM?

Comment: check your sdk installed location. configure it in the environment variables. Open the command prompt and trigger the AVD using the 'android list avd' command.

Answer (score 1):

I also faced this issue before some days when i updated HAXM. 
Before that update i was able to run Android Emulator.

After doing some research on this. Finally i solved it out.

Even i have enable VT-X tech and disabled secure boot. My Android Studio failed to load emulator saying `dev/kvm not found`.

This issue came after updating HAXM. I found some useful answers. which tell this issue is in HAXM 7.2.0. See [this issue on github](https://github.com/intel/haxm/issues/56)

**Steps to solve:**

- Uninstall Haxm from SDK manager.
- downloaded previous version of HAXM v7.1.0 from [this release page](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases).
- Install this HAXM.

**Update!**

If you are not able to solve this still after lot search and this solution, then you should use `GenyMotion` because it is very light weight (150mb ram) than Android Emulator (2gb ram). Also it is faster than Android Emulator (that hangs apps UI some time). GenyMotion is also suggested by [great developers](https://www.genymotion.com/).

Comment: Wow you have a great memory. That is exactly what is happening. I have to wait until the updating is finished but I will let you know. And Thank you very much for your help. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Let me know if it works for you. If so don't forget to mark right.

Comment: Not working, maybe I did not uninstall properly. It must be me because you sure nailed the error. I do not see where I can post images

Comment: You can post image, just go in edit mode of your question, then you will find on image post option on tab-bar of question window.

Comment: You can see them here  

https://www.tekfiles.com/2018/07/16/error-images/

Comment: This is the same issue i got, and i solved by installing old version of HAXM as i mentioned.

Comment: Even i solved this, but i have switched to Genymotion emulator, because it is much faster and light weight (150mb ram) than Android Emulator( consumes 2gb ram).